# Web API Route config not firing by angularjs with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Please check my WebApiConfig, API Controller and angular Service. 1st route is working fine but 2nd and 3rd not calling by angularjs. though web api route is ok.

**--WebApiConfig**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param}",
            defaults: new { param = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Api2",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}",
            defaults: new { param1 = RouteParameter.Optional, param2 = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Api3",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}/{param3}",
            defaults: new { param1 = RouteParameter.Optional, param2 = RouteParameter.Optional, param3 = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**--Web API Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult InsertAcademicInfo(AcademicInformation[] param1, AcademicResult[] param2)
{
     return Ok(_academic.InsertAcademicInformation(param1, param2).Data);
}
```

**--Angular Service**

```
mainApp.factory('AcademicServices', ['$http', '$rootScope', function ($http, $rootScope) {
  return {
    Save: function (academic, results) {
        return $http({
            url: '/Api/ApiAcademic/InsertAcademicInfo',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { param1: academic, param2: results },
            async: false
        });
    },
  };
}]);
```

Comment: As per your route `api/{controller}/{action}/{param1}/{param2}`: `param1` and `param2` are supposed to be present in the URL. However in your Http POST, the url is `api/ApiAcademic/InsertAcademicInfo` and the parameters are in the post body so this won't work! Can you include the rest of your controller and mention which actions work and which don't?

Comment: Api/ApiAcademic/Details(int param)  -- param(which working fine with first route)
Api/ApiAcademic/InsertAcademicInfo(AcademicInformation[] param1, AcademicResult[] param2)  -- Not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not how `post` works in Web API. What you are sending does not match what you are expecting. If you want to send data via the message body you need to send a single object, this object can be complex. This is what you are currently doing from your angular/javascript call but not what you are expecting in your web api method. Change your web api like the following to accomplish this.

Also you really should be using route attributes instead of trying to create a monolithic routing table that will accommodate all your routes across all your controllers. Use `RouteAttribute` and `RoutePrefixAttribute`. Also you do not need any parameters in the method below because you are sending the data using the requests message body and not in the URI.

**AcademicInfoModel.cs**

```
public class AcademicInfoModel {
    public AcademicInformation[] param1 {get;set;}
    public AcademicResult[] param2 {get;set;}
}
```

**ApiAcademicController.cs**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/ApiAcademic")]
public class ApiAcademicController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("InsertAcademicInfo")]
    public IHttpActionResult InsertAcademicInfo(AcademicInfoModel model)
    {
         return Ok(_academic.InsertAcademicInformation(model.param1, model.param2).Data);
    }
}
```

Comment: but i think this is a complex solution, though in jquery i have worked on it.

Comment: i need to send data url.

Comment: @sebu - why would you do that? If its an atomic value / simple type (like string, int, etc) then using the URI is fine but on a POST with complex data in an array sending in the message body is very much preferred.